# How to maintain different settings files in TFS

Tags: tfs

I'm currently working on integrating the TFS source control system at my work ... I run into one small problem ... I need different version of web.config (among other config files) for different branches (due to the environment that we're releasing the web application to). 
(for example - i don't want to merge the web.config file all the time even though there are differences ...)

Is there a good way to keep track of that (instead of manually diff-ing the files)?

thanks!

Comment: My feeling is that this question would be better served on SO, but I'm not totally convinced yet.

Comment: ok - that's fine - this wasn't really "coding" related that's why i didn't post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have seen so far is that people write installers that manipulate the settings that are needed. So you don't have to bother with other environments than the development environment. Also because in some companies the people in development aren't allowed knowledge of all the settings in the production environment.

I haven't used it myself but know/knew of people using web.config transformations. That might be an option for you.

- [Web Deployment: Web.Config Transformation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)
- [Visual Studio Web Config Transformations and TFS Build](http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/10/16/visual-studio-web-config-transformations-and-tfs-build.aspx)